# Mixing optional certificate authentication with Windows authentication in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, authorization, client-certificates

I have a .NET 6 app where I need to have different endpoints reacting to different authentication schemes. I curently support two types of JWT authentication (local authentication, OIDC) along with Windows auth. Now I'm trying to add certificate authentification (the idea being a differnet authentification endpoint, which checks the supplied certificate, and if there's one, issues a bearer token so the rest of the app can keep using bearer tokens).

My authentication controller allows to fetch tokens for multiple authorization schemes. The controller has no defined authorization scheme - the schemes are then set on individual methods

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

Then we have the ability to fetch an access token using Windows authentication, local authentification, and certificate authentification:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[HttpGet("Token")]
public IActionResult GenerateToken([FromQuery] string clientId = null)
{
  var userIdentity = User?.Identity?.Name;
  //
}
```

And for local auth

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("authenticate")]
public IActionResult Authenticate([FromBody] AuthenticateModel model, [FromQuery] string clientId = null)
{
  // validate login, issue token
}
```

Now I've added a third authentication method that looks at a certificate

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[HttpGet("Certificate")]
public IActionResult GenerateCertificateToken([FromQuery] string clientId = null)
{
    var cert = HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate;
    // get identity from certificate, validate, issue token
}
```

To support optional client certificates I'm using this code approach.

```
webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
{
    options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(options =>
    {
        options.ClientCertificateMode = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate;
     });
});
```

Most of my controllers then use the access token returned by the authentification controller's 3 methods to get a token. Sample controller:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UserController : ControllerBase
{
}
```

So far, all is good. Now I also have a bunch of controllers that do Windows authentification only

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[Route("Maintenance")]
public class MaintenanceController: BaseMaintenanceController
{
}

[ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]
public class BaseMaintenanceController: ControllerBase
{
}
```

The MaintenanceController is in a different namespace than BaseMaintenanceController, UserController and AuthentificationController (not sure if this matters).

When I do not register certificate authentification, things work as expected (except of course I cannot use `GenerateCertificateToken` because the auth scheme certificate is not registered. As soon as I register for certificate authentification, my `MaintenanceController` only throws 403s.

Here's how I register the authentification schemes in `Startup.cs` 's

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ....
    var authBuilder = services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        });

    var authPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

     authBuilder = authBuilder
           .AddNegotiate()
           .AddJwtBearer() // details omitted here
           .AddCertificate(u => 
            {
                u.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
                u.ValidateCertificateUse = true;
                u.ValidateValidityPeriod = true;
                u.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck; // for speed
            });

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultPolicy = authPolicyBuilder.Build();
        });
  
}
```

As soon as I have the `authBuilder.AddCertificate` call in `ConfigureServices`, my MaintenanceController keeps returning 403s. Remove the call to `AddCertificate` and `MaintenanceController` works fine again.Interestingly enough, the `GenerateToken` method in my `AuthentificationController` keeps working though.

Anybody has any idea why AddCertificate kills my controllers that use `NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme` for the entire controller, but leaves the `AuthentificationController.GenerateCertificateToken` running, even though it uses the same `Authorize` tag?

Comment: The certificate is for HTTPS (secure) that uses TLS and allow client to specify the certificate to use.  TLS is performed before the client sends the request.  The server sends a certificate block with a list of certificate names.  The client looks up in stores the certificate and finds a matching certificate. TLS when it fails does not return any response (since it is done before the request) so you would not get the 403 error.  So it sound like you are using HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

I figured, I'd see if me having a controller in a different Namespace would trip things up somehow, so added a new controller that performs negotiate, and from that point on, things started working, and kept working when I removed the controller I had added. I guess the sun needed top past the mid-day point or something.